# Is it possible to get refreshed entitlements from Azure AD withouth signing out an in again in Azure portal

Tags: azure, active-directory, azureportal

We are using myaccess.microsoft.com to grant access to different resources in the azure cloud. Whenever I do this it seems like I need to sign out and in again to the Azure Portal to have the new entitlements reflected there. This is rather tedious, is there some way to force a refreshed access token with the new permissions in some other way?

Comment: Did you get a chance to look into [AD entitlement management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/governance/entitlement-management-logs-and-reporting#create-custom-azure-monitor-queries-using-the-azure-portal)

Comment: Is your link correct @HarshithaV ? It links to "Create custom Azure Monitor queries using the Azure portal", and I dont really see the relevance? But my impression is that we are using entitlement managment when we are using myaccess.microsoft.com, and when we are granted access we are added to different AD groups. The problem is that I only seem to get "registered" as member of the new groups in portal.azure.com by logging in and out again.